# How do I find the mode of a list<double>?

Tags: c#

I have a list:

```
List<double> final=new List<double>();
final.Add(1);
final.Add(2);
final.Add(3);
```

What sort of method could I use to find the mode of this list? Also, if there are two modes, the function would return the smaller of the two.

Comment: What is the `List` mode?

Comment: I think he means the element that appears in the list most often. Have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29

Comment: You can explain a lttle more about  mode

Comment: @Edward: What are you looking for besides usr's answer?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
int? modeValue =
 final
 .GroupBy(x => x)
 .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).ThenBy(x => x.Key)
 .Select(x => (int?)x.Key)
 .FirstOrDefault();
```

All it takes are a few composed LINQ operations. You can also express the same with query expressions.

If the list is empty, `modeValue` will be `null`.

Comment: If you don't already know about LINQ, you might want to make yourself familiar with it. `int?` is a nullable type.

Comment: @EdwardKarak Nullable types are explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Answer (score 5):

The answer given by usr seems like it would do the trick, but if you are wanting something non-Linq, try this:

```
    public int? FindMode(List<int> sample)
    {
        if (sample == null || sample.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        List<int> indices = new List<int>();
        sample.Sort();

        //Calculate the Discrete derivative of the sample and record the indices
        //where it is positive.
        for (int i = 0; i < sample.Count; i++)
        {
            int derivative;

            if (i == sample.Count - 1)
            {
                //This ensures that there is a positive derivative for the
                //last item in the sample. Without this, the mode could not
                //also be the largest value in the sample.
                derivative = int.MaxValue - sample[i];
            }
            else
            {
                derivative = sample[i + 1] - sample[i];
            }

            if (derivative > 0)
            {
                indices.Add(i + 1);
            }
        }

        int maxDerivative = 0, maxDerivativeIndex = -1;

        //Calculate the discrete derivative of the indices, recording its
        //maxima and index.
        for (int i = -1; i < indices.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            int derivative;

            if (i == -1)
            {
                derivative = indices[0];
            }
            else
            {
                derivative = indices[i + 1] - indices[i];
            }

            if (derivative > maxDerivative)
            {
                maxDerivative = derivative;
                maxDerivativeIndex = i + 1;
            }
        }

        //The mode is then the value of the sample indexed by the
        //index of the largest derivative.
        return sample[indices[maxDerivativeIndex] - 1];
    }
```

What I've done here is essentially an implementation of the algorithm described on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29) in the section *Mode of a sample*. Note that by sorting the sample first, this will return the smaller mode in the multi-mode case.

Also, the Octave code on the Wikipedia page assumes 1-based indexing; because C# is 0-based, you'll see I used `indices.Add(i + 1)` and `maxDerivativeIndex = i + 1` to compensate. For the same reason I also used `indices[maxDerivativeIndex] - 1` to map back to 0-based indexing when returning the final mode.

---

Because this method is a little less obvious than the intuitive method of using a `Dictionary` to accumulate counts, here is a sort of worked example.

Calling the above method:

```
int? mode = FindMode(new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 12, 12, 17 }));
```

After that initial check and sort, the discrete derivative (i.e., the `indices` list) will look like this at the end of that first for loop:

```
[1, 2, 6, 8, 10, 11]
```

Next, we calculate the [discrete derivative](http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Discrete_derivative)  of `indices`. For efficiency reasons I am not storing these in a list (we only want the largest of them, after all), but they work out to be:

```
[1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1]
```

Therefore, `maxDerivative` ends up being 4, and `maxDerivativeIndex` 2. Hence:

```
sample[indices[maxDerivativeIndex] - 1]
    -> sample[indices[2] - 1]
    -> sample[6 - 1]
    -> 6
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution:

```
var counts = final
    .Distinct()
    .Select(o => new { Value = o, Count = final.Count(c => c == o) })
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Count);
```

This will return a collection indicating how many times each of the values appears in the list, with the most popular (mean) first. You can get to this using `counts.FirstOrDefault();`, but a collection may be more useful as you'll be able to see when there is more than one mode!

I find `GroupBy` LINQ queries can be a bit tricky to understand, but that's my personal opinion.

Comment: what about 
`var distinct=final.Distinct();
var modes=distinct.Except<int>(distinct);`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution that is more correct due to the other methods not returning all numbers if they occur the same amount of times

Input: 1,2,3,4,5

Output: 1,2,3,4,5

Input: 1,1,2,2

Output: 1,2

Input: 1,1,2,4,5
Output 1

```
string getMode()
    {
        IDictionary<float, int> mode = new Dictionary<float, int>();    //Dictionary (Float is the number) (Int is  the occurences)
        foreach (float number in numbers)                               //Loop through List named numbers (List is made of floats)
        {
            if (mode.ContainsKey(number))                               //If dictionary already contains current number increase occurences by 1
            {
                mode[number] ++;
            }
            else
            {
                mode.Add(number, 1);                                    //If dictionary does not contain current number add new occurence
            }
        }

        List<float> currentMax = new List<float>();                     //Create new List of the max number
        int occurences = 0;                                             //Max occurences
        bool foundMultiple = false;                                     //Check if multiple found
        foreach (KeyValuePair<float, int> entry in mode.Reverse())      //Loop through dictionary
        {
            if(occurences < entry.Value)                                //If occurences is smaller than current input
                                                                        //Clear old input and add current number to list
            {
                currentMax.Clear();
                currentMax.Add(entry.Key);
                occurences = entry.Value;
                foundMultiple = false;
            }
            else if(occurences == entry.Value)                          //If number with the same amount of occurences occures
                                                                        //Add to List
            {
                currentMax.Add(entry.Key);
                foundMultiple = true;
            }
        }

        string returnText = "";                                         //Text to return
        if(foundMultiple == true)                                           
        {
           foreach(float number in currentMax)                          //Loop through text
            {
                returnText += number.ToString() + ",";                  //Add to return text
            }
        }
        else
        {
            returnText = currentMax[0].ToString();                         //If there aren't multiple return just first index
        }

        if (returnText.EndsWith(","))
        {
            returnText = returnText.Remove(returnText.Length - 1);      //Format string to avoid a comma at the end
        }
        return returnText;
    }
```