# Find the mode in a list of doubles C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, math, statistics

I'm making a program using C# that calculates measures of variation and measures of center in statistics. So the user inputs a list of numbers and it adds the numbers to a list. I want the program to be able to find the mode (If there is one) of the list and then return it. I also want it to return the modes separated by commas if there is multiple modes.

[Wikipedia Mode Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics))

Comment: I tried the code on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467492/how-do-i-find-the-mode-of-a-listdouble?rq=1 but they don't do what I need.

Comment: Well yes, you'd need to tweak it a bit yourself. But the logic is pretty straight forward: 1. Find the maximum count of duplicates in the list. 2. Find all items which have the same amount of duplicates as the maximum.

Comment: But how do I count the duplicates?

Comment: @NumNumDude At this point you're really asking people to do your work for you. I'm sure searching for `C# count duplicates` will give you plenty of information as to where to look next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work, it really is quite trivial.
(It could be optimized probably ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ )

```
var items = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 6, 2, 8, 8 };
var grouped = items.GroupBy(i => i).Select(i => new { value = i.Key, count = i.Count() });
var maxCount = grouped.Max(g => g.count);
var mode = grouped.Where(g => g.count == maxCount);
```